# Creating a list of dictionaries modifying just one values at each step

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which describes a set of parameters like this:

```
params = {'V0': 0.040239623194206875, 'theta': 0.2133407345978868,
 'omega': 0.8624391468911115, 'kappa': 0.8632687388218084,
 'rho': -0.7680944602881048}
```

Each parameter in the set has a constant number which represent its variation. From such set I want to construct a list of dictionaries until I have 100 sets of parameters. The logic behind is that I want for example change `params['V0']` to

```
params['V0'] += deltaV0 
params['V0'] -= deltaV0
```

with the other values fixed, obtaining another 2 different dictionaries to add to my list. My problem is that I can't manage to transform my idea in code. The framework should be something like:

```
good_set = [params]

while len(good_set) < 100:


good_set.append(new params)
```

How can I efficiently obtain new dictionaries from the initial one? I need to simultaneously obtain 2 new dictionaries from the initial one for each parameters ( because the variation is added and subtracted each time), so in total for each iteration I should add to my list 5*2=10 dictionaries. I red some question about dict comprehension but they didn't give me an input to solve my problem

Comment: copy the original dict `params.copy()` then modify the copy. would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just need to create a `.copy` of the dict, and then change it suitably. For exmaple:

```
In [3]: params = {'V0': 0.040239623194206875, 'theta': 0.2133407345978868,
   ...:  'omega': 0.8624391468911115, 'kappa': 0.8632687388218084,
   ...:  'rho': -0.7680944602881048}
   ...: 

In [4]: results = []

In [5]: import random

In [6]: for _ in xrange(100):
   ...:     sample_params = params.copy()
   ...:     sample_params['V0'] += random.random()
   ...:     results.append(sample_params)
```

I've used `random.random()` as the delta value, you can have custom logic to modify in which manner required.

---

If your delta are constant, and they can either be added, subtracted or not considered for test case generation, you can try

```
params = {'V0': 0.040239623194206875, 'theta': 0.2133407345978868,
 'omega': 0.8624391468911115, 'kappa': 0.8632687388218084,
 'rho': -0.7680944602881048}

import random

delta = {'V0': random.random(),
'theta': random.random(),
'omega': random.random(),
'kappa': random.random(),
'rho': random.random()}

list_of_params = [ {key: params[key] + random.randint(-1, 1) * delta[key] for key in params} for _ in xrange(100)]
```

Here, the delta are stored in a dict, and `random.randint(-1, 1)` takes care of randomly adding, subtracting, or ignoring the particular delta.

Comment: That is a good starting point. However, in this way I add just another new dictionary for 100 times. I would add it 1 times contemporarily to 9 another dictionaries which consider up and down variation for the other parameters. I know that I am asking a lot. I just wondering if it is possible to do it in just one passage and then repeat the same procedure over the new dictionaries obtained.

Comment: @Alexbrini I am not sure if I am getting your right, but however you may choose to do it, you will end up creating a 100 copies. Now if you have a way of genrating the delta, you can do it using a dict comprehension. However, that is still, essentially, 100 copies. I've added a hypothetical example for this scenario, but you will need to ask a fresh question within a very controlled scope to get the answer you are seeking.

Comment: @Alexbrini In the meantime, if my answer helped, don't forget to accept it by ticking it :)

Comment: @ mu 無  Is it possible that using `random.randint(-1, 1)` we never add the delta because the 1 is excluded?

Comment: @Alexbrini I remember in python2 documentation both the numbers of range are inclusive for randint, so randint(-1, 1) will randomly emit -1, 0 or 1. You may have to check for other python versions.